# VS code debugging

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Everytime I try to run the debugger in VS code its say configuration javascript debugger terminal is missing in "launch json". is there a way to fix this? or should I be using a different debugger? my debugger is Javascript debugger Nightly.

I don't know much about json settings, but I've tried to re-installing it whicih did nothing, I have never been able to use it and it has been this way since I got this extension and I'm starting to believe it's the extension.

Comment: As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587) Also, please show the _exact_ error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to the launch.json file. The example assumes that you are debugging a Node.js application, so if you are debugging smth different you will need to adjust it accordingly.

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Debug Node.js",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/index.js",
    "console": "integratedTerminal"
}
```